# Get cPanel back from the ads after testing multiple nameservers?

Tags: redirect, dns, cpanel, ads

I have 2 domain names. One linked to an old lifetime host that is not known. And another one linked to a new lifetime host that is not known. Before the link of the second domain name, I did try a free hosting on both of my domain names.

On the first domain name, I did keep old nameservers and did add new nameservers just for test, then deleted the test nameservers, then deleted the domain name in the free hosting. But still I did not find a way to retrieve my old cpanel at my lifetime host, because the free hosting did add SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER + their adds as redirect of my domain name without my will and without my whois, as my domain name is well kept at Go Daddy.

On the second domain name, I did retrieve my new cpanel, from the new lifetime unknown host, but it took many hours of waiting, the adds where there but not the security issue.

I did not keep my free hosting because they are difficult to track as their real name is a " their real name ".w3bin.com and as their ping is related to many hosting companies that control the web in many countries, so it's the same kind of ping from here, oh no here, oh no here, then the ones that robs domain names, aka with bifurcations (yes I ping everything). And because as for this reason I wasn't going to buy a host on them (and also because I can't afford many times billing on a no future), so the reputation was that if I build a website there, and I did not buy nothing at them, it will do pof in 2 months.

So I did retrieve one cpanel on 2 with this test.

How can I retrieve my old time cpanel ? From the ads of a test host I did quit nameservers and link to domain name. There was no content with my first domain name. I did chmod the content of my second domain name to delete it. ... but I will chmod everyting to /.

My nameservers are correct, and there is nothing suspicious on my old domain name: https://intodns.com/faie-turritopsis-dohrnii.com
I also do have for 12months Premium DNS on GoDaddy but for me it's enigmatic as I have no idea of how to fill nothing.

Maybe it's time, maybe I should do something, I will contact my old lifetime host also.

Comment: I did a complaint to WHOIS but the problem is: it is not my regitrar neither my hosting that did suspend my account, it is a test hosting website I did not stay in. They do redirect over my website with their ads so to take control over my domain name after I quit them. Even though there is not this choice on the Whois, I did the complaint. The  redirect of my domain name to http://suspended-website.com/i/ and all their letters is illegal. As people I know don't complain, I do complain. There is nothing wrong with my dns codes. It's the ads code I can't see that are wrong and illegal. =)

Comment: I could not reach GoDaddy, but I did left the worst ticket anyone would read with my real name asking my test hosting to delete my account. Hoping to kill their happiness as they wish to kill mine.

Comment: Hello I will travel tomorrow and will watch if anything moves in 1 week. WHOIS did contact GoDaddy that didn't contact me and who put solved on the problem history by doing refresh. So the fact of my domain name being overwritten by a big company ad + suspended + error is not a WHOIS problem (neither a hosting problem). So it's something else I don't have access to. But I won't give away my future website for ads that eats DNS they don't own. No, I have my dreams on it. =)

Comment: I put a suspicious IP that makes me remember (would need to check) a friends of mine website that was stolen by something alike, it no more redirects to the other big french internet company, weird: http://39.ip-37-187-64.eu/ I believe they did cut it for no one to know whom my testing hosting belong to, so I do relate this IP not only to ads but also to hackers, think what you feel, I am not in informatics.

Comment: I confirm it to be hacking, as my 2nd website that was a bought hosting has same issue: was overwritten by ads.

Comment: https://intodns.com/forum-creation-artistique-vs-vecu-paranormal.com nothing in, site redirect does not come from my dns in this website neither. I'm out for a week. 2 websites, ads are overwritting my DNS that belongs to me. 2 small lifetime personal beloved hosting companies, no link. Link was just free hosting I tested from big company. Ads are not from my DNS.

Comment: A good advice: do never try correcting intodns.com or other website that says what is wrong in your SOA file. Those parent nameservers R FC2181 5.4.1 and other errors that makes the people in informatics edit their DNS text file so for it to give no errors are in fact security issues in the DNS SOA whatsoever file that allows hackers to one day rob your internet identity, your DNS and sell your websites as if they were your registrar or as if they were allowed to transfer it. Your DNS or SOA whatever is to stay with its errors. It's more secure to keep the errors. As I did keep them.

Comment: And for the moment you can only find the snake that eat its head but not the guilty one as it can hide and as it uses alternative ads system to bypass DNS rights and redirect DNS they don't own into ads, phishing, password stealing. So normal if some of the CPanels that needs your correct DNS to login do become unavailable for security reasons like: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER as they can steal your password.

Comment: So there is a lot of security to be improved in what concerns DNS as it's not the only system that exists, and as the ads can redirect any DNS they don't own if they have a small re-direct link somewhere you can't see to their servers. And no one DNS account can be suspended by a past website that is not your DNS registrar, that is nonsense. As only those who own you can suspend you. And thank you a lot for my real 2 hostings, whois and true registrar and for whoever went solving my problem. =) Thank you ;D